Expression not supported: Convert(x.Id, BsonObjectId) after Upgrade
After I upgraded mongodb drivers and .net framework to .net 8 I a Exceptionwhen I try to query elementy by their BsonObjectId.

Expression not supported: Convert(x.Id, BsonObjectId).

        BsonObjectId id = BsonObjectId.Create(commitId);
        var query = Filters.Eq(x => x.Id, id);
        var result = await Collection.Find(query).FirstAsync();

The id property in the Dto I use for mongodb is defined as followed
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

Any advice what change I did miss?

What if you replace the id variable with: ObjectId id = ObjectId.Parse(commitId);? https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.9/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Bson_ObjectId_Parse.htm

Mostlikely the reason is that new drivers use Linq3 provider by default (old drivers use Linq2) and for some reason BsonObjectId is not supported. As suggested above, ObjectId probably will help, but if not, see common recommendation in this case: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/faq/#why-are-certain-linq-or-builder-expressions-unsupported-. You can also configure Linq2 provider in MongoClientSettings, but it's not recommended approach
